# Spring boot, @ManyToMany, create a repository for the join Table

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the two entities with a manyToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String CategoryName;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    private List<ProductEntity> products = new ArrayList<ProductEntity>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class ProductEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="price")
    private Float price;

    @Column(name="rating")
    private Float rating;

    @Column(name="image")
    private String image;

    @Column(name="quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "product_category",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")}
    )
    private List<CategoryEntity> categories = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In the database I have a join Table product_category that hold the product_id and category_id.
**my question is how to add element to the joinTable product_category? is it possible to create a Repository even if we don't have an entities??**

I tried this with my controller:

```
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductMapper productMapper;
    @Autowired
    private CategoryMapper categoryMapper;
    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductReviewService reviewService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductReviewMapper reviewMapper;

    @PostMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductDto> createProduct(@RequestBody ProductDto productDto) {
        ProductEntity productEntity=productMapper.dtoToEntity(productDto);
        for(CategoryDto categoryDto:productDto.getCategories()){
            CategoryEntity categoryEntity=categoryMapper.dtoToEntity(categoryDto);
            productEntity.getCategories().add(categoryEntity);
        }
        productEntity=productService.saveProduct(productEntity);
        productDto.setProductId(productEntity.getProductId());

        return ResponseEntity.created(null).body(productDto);
    }
}
```

but I got this:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.be.ec.entities.CategoryEntity
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have relationship consistency issue. you are adding a category to a product but not adding product into category

add this method into your ProductEntity class:

```
 public void addCategory(CategoryEntity category) {
        this.getCategories().add(category);
        category.getProducts().add(this);
    }
```

and use this method to add category into product.

```
ProductEntity productEntity=productMapper.dtoToEntity(productDto);
for(CategoryDto categoryDto:productDto.getCategories()){
    CategoryEntity categoryEntity=categoryMapper.dtoToEntity(categoryDto);
    productEntity.addCategory(categoryEntity); //changed line
   }
productEntity=productService.saveProduct(productEntity);
productDto.setProductId(productEntity.getProductId());
```